# Sorting filter 'orderBy' doesn't work in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a table list with three columns. There are the possibility to sort all columns up an down. When you click on the -Tag then the list will sorted but I'm getting the error message:

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: orderbyFilterProvider <-

Here is the Ctrl:

```
var orderby = $filter('orderby');

$scope.sortType = '-maxAge';
$scope.sortReverse = false;

$scope.order = function (sortType, sortReverse) {
   $scope.nameslist = orderby($scope.nameslist, sortType, sortReverse);
};
```

The view (header):

```
...
<th>
  <a href="" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse; order('fname',reverse)">
     Firstame
     <span ng-show="sortType=='fname' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
     <span ng-show="sortType=='fname' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
  </a>
</th>
...
```

The view (table list):

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredNames = (nameslist | orderBy: sortType:sortReverse)" class="show-cursor">
   <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

I don't know where is the problem?!

Comment: Can you give js fiddle link here . Then  we can decide what is the problem in easiest way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use camel case its order**B**y not order**b**y in your controller

```
var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
```

Comment: thanksss :) .. one question.. How can I reduce the ngClick input or the span ngShow input?